# Ionic video player android and ios issue

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have used this plugin [cordova video plugin](https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer)

it is working fine on **android** phone but not working **ios**.

so I have used **Html5 video player**

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

this code is not working on android phone. Is it working on ios?  pls can you tell me? which video player support on android and ios phone?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand Ionic has issues with embedding local videos using the HTML5 video tag, however you can open the video using *fileOpener2* with *ngCordova*. It's easy to do this and you only have to know the file mime type to open whatever you need.

Comment: Providing an example would go a long way in making this answer more helpful.

Comment: Your answers is wrong. I am actually using embedding local videos using ionic 1.3. This is what I am using  <video id="article{{$index + 1}}" preload="metadata" x-webkit-airplay="allow" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayerSingle article{{$index + 1}}">
            <source src="{{video.url}}" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>